# Get an URL date using inurl on Google Custom Search API

Tags: google-api, metadata, google-custom-search

How can I know when an URL was added into Google index using the GCS (Google Custom Search API)? I know I can get it throw the "inurl" parameter, but only on regular Google Search, like example below:

https://www.google.com.br/search?q=inurl%3Amoz.com%2Fblog%2F25-killer-combos-for-googles-site-operator

[image]

If someone have some code in java, I'll be glad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort by date ?
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_search?hl=ja#sort_by_attribute
makes dates show, where available ...
Worth a try - I'm no expert !

Comment: thx, but I want the date field, and this option just return an sorted result, and don't show me a date like a timestamp. :/